# why tf.placeholder does not work correctly to feed?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I did as below, but wrong info is:
"**InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype string
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholderdtype=DT_STRING, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]**"

```
pattern = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])

filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once(pattern[0])
count_num_files = tf.size(filenames)
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
image_reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
image_name, image_file = image_reader.read(filename_queue)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    feed_dict = {pattern: ['/home/test/images/*.jpg']} 
    out = sess.run(image_name, feed_dict)

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

I think every step is corret. but it really does not work as I have said.
What is wrong? I really need your help, which makes me confused for a long time.
Thank yo very much!

Suppl.
////////////////////////////
Thank you the friend below give the answer.
Another question is how to change the initial placeholder value.
Look code below, first I init placehoder y as blank '',then I change it to string pattern,but in fact, y is always is blank '', no change, how to chagne y to another value?Thanks a lot

```
pattern = '/home/lyp/MyTensorflowData/TestProject/images/*.jpg'
y = tf.placeholder(tf.string)
filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once(y)
count_num_files = tf.size(filenames)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op, feed_dict={y: ''})
  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  for epoch in range(3):
    print(sess.run(count_num_files, feed_dict={y: pattern}))


coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: Show us the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with how you initialize your variables. I'm actually not entirely sure why, but this worked for me (v0.1.0):

`tf.global_variables_initializes().run(feed_dict)`

It seems that to initialize your variables, you need to pass in the feed_dict

Comment: Thank you very much. it works here. but If I want to change the feed_dict value in a loop, it looks a little hard. any good idea?'